# Good solution to sending attachments via email

Tags: email, file-transfer, attachments, upload

I have a lot of problems with sending attachments with my email, either the file can't be scanned for viruses so fails, or exceeds the filesize limit (2/5/10MB), or there are simply too many files (+20) and my email/webmail/client hangs up leaving me unsure whether to retry, or let the mail get sent anyhow.

I've tried many methods in the past but they all had some problems:

- [Pando](http://www.pando.com/) requires my recipient to download its 4MB client before file transfer can begin.
- Free file hosting like [DepositFiles](http://depositfiles.com/) requires recipients to wait some time before downloading.

Is there a solution to this? most importantly a system that's easy for recipients to download from?

Comment: Shouldn't title be something like: "Good alternative to sending files via email?"  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a Dropbox account and copy/paste link to the file in "Public" folder. Just remove them after a few weeks when recipient downloaded the file.

Yes, it's a "hack", but it might be more convenient than having to upload files to one of those "file hosting" websites.

Comment: Just want to add that people can use DropBox through the web without having to download/install the client.

Comment: An illustrated tour of DropBox, woot! - http://www.getdropbox.com/tour#1

Answer (score 4):

You could try **drop.io** (similar to Dropbox) or **MediaFire** (one-click) hosting. Both have free plans without waiting times or bandwidth limits.

Comment: Just to note, from their website:We've discontinued the ability to create free drops from the homepage. Read our our blog for more details. 

To create drops at this time you must have a previously established account.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (beta) solution that keeps you in control of your own files - [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/). They've got a very fast server built-in, and methods to bypass firewalls so one can easily serve your own files over the web. The current 10.1 snapshots contain the latest release:

http://my.opera.com/unite/blog/

I use it to serve out large files that mail would choke on, but I want to keep hosted on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

What I do, which I'll admit isn't for everyone, is drop the files on a web server using WebDAV and e-mail a link. The recipient has to try real hard to mess it up! Which, unfortunately, has been the problem in pretty much every other technique I've tried. Other pluses, I can delete it, replace it, etc., whenever I want. Shared hosting is cheap or you could do it home-brew style on an old computer and a dynamic DNS updater.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [StreamFile](http://streamfile.com/) or [HotShare](http://www.hotshare.net/en/)

Answer (score 1):

Keep exploring the file hosting options. You'll find some good ones.

I've had luck with [sendspace](http://sendspace.com/) and [YouSendIt](http://www.yousendit.com/). I can't remember whether these have wait times but try them out

Edit: No wait time on sendspace but files *do* expire after a certain amount of time

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but you can accomplish what you want with [File Savr](http://www.filesavr.com/):

> FileSavr's goal is to simplify the
>   process of file hosting. We provide
>   fastest and easiest file hosting
>   service as an alternative to sites
>   like MegaUpload and RapidShare. Unlike
>   the other sites, we do not force users
>   to sign up for paid accounts to
>   download files, we do not show long
>   countdown timers, pop up ads, or any
>   other spam related activities. Our
>   goal is simple, to offer the most
>   basic file hosting service so you can
>   share your stuff quickly.
>
> **Why is FileSavr doing this?**   To make
>   the process a lot simpler, and because
>   we know how annoying it is to not be
>   able to share files.
>
> **How long are the files kept?**    The
>   files are kept forever as long as they
>   are being downloaded.
>
> **Is the upload size really 10 GB?** 
>   Yes.

Answer (score 1):

try http://streamfile.com/ which i recently discovered. its limit is 150mb and you can send multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to Amazon S3 and give out the signed URL that expires after some time. For example with [Cyberduck](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#PublicURLs).

Answer (score 0):

Several websites of previous answers are offline thus I'll add a more recent website. I'm surprised it hasn't been mentioned before:

https://www.wetransfer.com/

Up to 2GB per file.

Answer (score 0):

https://instant.io is what you want. It works using WebTorrent so you can start downloading right away.

There's also https://send.firefox.com/ which lets you upload and encrypt large files (up to 1GB) to share online. When you upload a file, Send creates a link to pass along to whoever you want. Each link created by Send will expire after 1 download or 24 hours, and all sent files will be automatically deleted from the Send server.

Both are free and free software (https://github.com/webtorrent/instant.io and https://github.com/mozilla/send).