# Is it possible to torrent files privately?

Tags: bittorrent, file-transfer

Is it possible to transfer files via a bittorrent client, in a way thats private? Maybe I have to install my own "tracker" server. Is this possible? and safe? I was looking at torrents as a general purpose solution to my [file transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/28313/good-solution-to-sending-attachments-via-email) problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set up a private tracker, but I don't think BT will suit your particular problem. BT is best suited to distributing the same large file to a large group of people; it really isn't intended to be used for sending a few files to a single person.

Comment: You could use BT to share a few files to a few computers

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should have a look at this article?

- [16 Apps That Make Sharing Large Files A Snap](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/08/08/16-apps-that-make-sharing-large-files-a-snap/)

Answer (score 2):

If you can setup a BT server why can't you set up an FTP server (did i miss something) ? :)