# What are good options for sending files that are too big for e-mail

Tags: file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good solution to sending attachments via email](https://superuser.com/questions/28313/good-solution-to-sending-attachments-via-email)

Hello,

I have a 30Mb file that is too big for my and for recipient's e-mail. It's a pdf, so compression won't really reduce the size. Using media/mail is not feasible.
 What are good, (i.e. secure, free) options exist for sending files outside of e-mail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Dropio. http://drop.io/. Simple, simple, simple. Free, Free, Free.

Comment: thanks, it actually worked pretty well; web-interface is a plus.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/features)

this company provides both Free and Paid Services {free = **2gb** disk space} and uploading and downloading is so easy and speedy and secure - just use their desktop application to upload the files into your personal account then the application will give u a link for the file which u can share with your friend, Its also used for Online backup and Public Shares.

*also*, If you're using **Ubuntu** then u must give **UbuntuOne** a try..

Comment: this seems to be the most popular option. For some reason I couldn't get it installed on my iMac (errors), so I used one of the other suggested services.

Answer (score 1):

The old defacto standard was ZIPping or RARing files, but these days I'd go eslambasha's route.  There are many file sending/hosting services these days.  Dropbox is good, and yousendit.com and sendspace.com are popular, hotfile.com and rapidshare.com are monstrously popular.  Depending on the level of security you need, you may not be able to do the one-click, no-registration method, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to split the file into parts and send them using multiple emails.

Answer (score 1):

Google Documents now has the facility to upload files of any type to it, so you could upload your PDF to Google Documents and send the link to your recipient.

To be honest I would probably go for DropBox as well for the ease of use but I just thought I would give this other alternative!

Comment: You need a Google Apps Premier Account to upload aribtrary files.

Comment: @David, sorry, that isn't true. I have both a Google Apps Premier account at work and several personal Google accounts for home. I'm looking at my Google Docs list for one of the personal accounts at the moment and it includes ZIP files and other non document files I've uploaded to it.

Answer (score 1):

[ZendTo](http://zend.to/) is a system which has been developed for such a situation as this.   It enables files to be uploaded to a server and then retrieved using a link that's emailed to the recipient. I've used it as hosted by my Uni and it seems to be pretty reliable.

Answer (score 1):

[AirDropper](https://www.airdropper.com/) is a wonderful little utility that basically sends a request to someone for a file and it will drop it directly into your Dropbox folder.  It allows you to give the person who needs to send you the file the correct permissions, etc and then simply turns off.  It can even do multi file uploads which is equally pretty cool.

(100 % Free)